# Php, mod_rewrite - парсинг переданной ссылки из подкаталога

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Как лучше осуществить парсинг ссылки, переданной `mod_rewrite` и полученной скриптом? У меня не возникает проблaем с разбором ссылки вида:

```
domainname/controller/action?parameter
```

если скрипт лежит в корне домена и `mod_rewrite` перенаправляет на `domainname/index.php`
Но если тот же скрипт находится в каком-нибудь каталоге, например `domainname/script/index.php`
то значение переменной `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` становится `"/script/controller/action?parameter"` и функция обработки принимает первое значение "script" за `controller`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь способ, желательно без использования регулярных выражений, для корректного парсинга ссылки, независимо от того, в каком каталоге находится скрипт, в корневом или подкаталоге?

По-другому: как можно обрезать `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` так, чтобы скрипт сам определил в каком каталоге он находится, сопоставил, и с соответствующего слэша начал парсинг?

Понимаю, что можно указать вручную местонахождение скрипта, чтобы он знал как именно парсить `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, но задача сделать универсальный сценарий, который бы корректно работал, независимо от того, в каком именно каталоге или подкаталоге сервера он находится.

Comment: https://htmlweb.ru/php/htaccess-mod_rewrite-rewritebase.php может rewrite base поможет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что для поставленной задачи достаточно парсить переменную `QUERY_STRING`, а не `REQUEST_URI`. Она передаёт как раз необходимую часть URI.